# getMore error when performing forEach function over cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am having a problem while performing an update over one of my collections.

The problem is that when I run my function, after about 10-15 minutes I  get the following error:

The version of mongo im using is: 2.4.6

```
Error: getMore: cursor didn't exist on server, possible restart or timeout? src/mongo/shell/query.js:113
```

The update is not so complex, but it is costly because first I have to find all the documents that fulfil the criteria, and go through each document with a forEach function to get a value form another collection, once I have this value I save de document and perform and update over one of the fields. Here is the code

```
db.events.find({'$or':[{'event.type':'EXBC'},{'event.type':'ENBC'}],'event.value.major':{'$exists':true}}).forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.regions.findOne({ 'beaconId.major': doc1.event.value.major,'beaconId.minor':doc1.event.value.minor,'group.uuid':doc1.event.value.uuid });

if (doc2 != null) {

    doc1.event.value.beacon = doc2._id;
    db.events.save(doc1);
    //OPTIONAL, I THINK IT TAKES TOO MUCH TIME THIS WAY


    if(doc1.event.type == "EXBC"){
    db.events.update({'_id':doc1._id}, {$set:{'event.source':'SDK','event.type':'MOB','event.extType':'BCN','event.action':'EXT'},
                                                 $unset:{'event.value.major':'','event.value.minor':'','event.value.uuid':''}});
    }

    else{
    db.events.update({'_id':doc1._id}, {$set:{'event.source':'SDK','event.type':'MOB','event.extType':'BCN','event.action':'ENT'},
                                                 $unset:{'event.value.major':'','event.value.minor':'','event.value.uuid':''}});
    }
}   
});
```

Please if someone can help me figuring out what I am doing wrong I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you get an error 10-15 minutes after you have created the initial cursor?  If so, MongoDB closes the cursor on the server side after 10 minutes of inactivity to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, That is what is happening, I just don't know how to avoid mongo closing the cursor after 10 minutes.

Comment: You cant control it -- you need to change your logic.  There is an option not to close the cursor, but this literally means that you are introducing a memory leak on the server side. Its not a solution.